# How to fix this compile error during rocksdb(make static_lib)?

Tags: c++

I downloaded the source code from github(https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb), and run make static_lib, then I get the following error.

Should I install all dependent libraries first? But I don't have permission to install.

Is there anyone can help me fix this make error?

```
  CC       env/io_posix.o
env/io_posix.cc: In member function ‘virtual rocksdb::Status rocksdb::PosixMmapFile::Allocate(uint64_t, uint64_t)’:
env/io_posix.cc:812:52: error: ‘FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE’ was not declared in this scope
         fallocate(fd_, fallocate_with_keep_size_ ? FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE : 0,
                                                    ^
env/io_posix.cc: In member function ‘virtual rocksdb::Status rocksdb::PosixWritableFile::Allocate(uint64_t, uint64_t)’:
env/io_posix.cc:1019:52: error: ‘FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE’ was not declared in this scope
         fallocate(fd_, fallocate_with_keep_size_ ? FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE : 0,
                                                    ^
make: *** [env/io_posix.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Which OS and version are you compiling this on? There is a [recent glibc bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1476120) that might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I  downloaded the release version of rocksdb again and fix this error. I am just so stupid.